# app crashes if we keep device idle for longtime

Tags: android, crash

if i opened my app and kept the device **idle** for a **long time**, my app is **crashing** when i unlock the phone/device. Why it is happening?

Comment: what RU doing in your app.

Comment: my app consists of single activity and many fragments

Answer (score 2):

The activities do not correctly implement the lifecycle (onPause, onStop, onStart, onResume). Maybe you are assuming that your application stays in memory all the time.

For more information please consult the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)